# Finding Finite Abelian Group

Tags: group-theory

Can someone explain to me how to find $a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$ such that $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15} = \langle a_1, a_2\rangle$

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One conceptual (though a bit involved in this small case) approach would be through the [CRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

You have an isomorphism of rings
$$
\Bbb{Z}_{15} \to \Bbb{Z}_{3} \times \Bbb{Z}_{5},
\qquad
[a]_{15} \mapsto ([a]_{3}, [a]_{5}).\tag{CRT}
$$
This yields an isomorphism of multiplicative groups
$$
\Bbb{Z}_{15}^{\star} \to \Bbb{Z}_{3}^{\star} \times \Bbb{Z}_{5}^{\star}.
$$
Now $\Bbb{Z}_{3}^{\star} = \langle 2 \rangle$ and $\Bbb{Z}_{5}^{\star} = \langle 2 \rangle$, so 
$$
\Bbb{Z}_{3}^{\star} \times \Bbb{Z}_{5}^{\star}
=
\left\langle ([2]_{3}, [1]_{5}), ([1]_{3}, [2]_{5}) \right\rangle.
$$

Take thus for $a_{1}, a_{2}$ counterimages of $([2]_{3}, [1]_{5})$ and $([1]_{3}, [2]_{5})$ via the map (CRT).

> You obtain $a_1 = [11]_{15}$ and $a_{2} = [7]_{15}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$\Bbb Z^*_{15}\cong \Bbb Z^*_3\times \Bbb Z^*_5\cong C_2\times C_4$$

take any element $\,a_1\in\Bbb Z_{15}\,$ with multiplicative order $\,4\,$ and any element $\,a_2\neq a_1^2\,$ of multiplicative order $\,2\,$ and their direct product $\,\langle a_1\rangle\times\langle a_2\rangle\cong\Bbb Z^*_{15}\,$

Answer (score 0):

Just start off by choosing any two elements and check what they generate. If they generate all of $\mathbb Z_{15}^*$, then you are done. Otherwise, pick some other two elements and check again. Pretty soon you'll find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ \Bbb Z_{15}^* =\, \pm\{1,2,4,8\} =\, \pm\, 2^n$